# What kinds of altimeter are used in modern airliners?

Tags: airliner, flight-instruments, altimeter

What's the mechanism of the altimeters in big jets?

Comment: Related: [Recent *blancolirio* video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=942KXXmMJdY) (background and potential interference problems for radar altimeters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Captain's and First Officer's **electric altimeters** have their pressure data (from static ports) processed by separate Air  Data Computers (ADC or ADIRU, etc. *nomenclature depending on the Manufacturer*).

Generally, there is a **Standby Altimeter** which is mechanical (pneumatic) with pressure received from alternate static ports.

Another type of altimeter is called a **radio altimeter** (sometimes called a radar altimeter), which uses radio signals (from antennas located on the bottom of the aircraft) to measure the absolute altitude/height of the aircraft directly above the terrain/surface below. It integrates with several aircraft systems. Of note, it is used by pilots to define the minimum altitude/height allowed to continue the descent before visually sighting specific elements of the landing environment for certain types of instrument approaches. Lastly, the display in the cockpit typically will display altitudes below 2500 ft (sometimes 5000 ft) above the surface directly below the aircraft.

Comment: There are [radar altimeters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_altimeter#Civil_aviation_applications) as well.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I agree and will add some info. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

**Main instruments**

In large aircraft, main altimeters are not separate mechanical altimeters. Instead the pitots, static probes and angle of attack probes, which are redundant, have their outputs digitalized by analog to digital converters (ADM: air data modules):

[image]

<sup>Pitot/static pressure converter, [source](https://aerospace.honeywell.com/us/en/learn/products/sensors/air-data-modules)</sup>

Digital data are send using a bus and processed by air data units, often coupled with the inertial units, sometimes also with GNSS (ADIRU/GNADIRU for Airbus).

[image]

<sup>A330 air probes and ADIRU, from A330 FCOM</sup>

ADIRU are computers, located in the avionics bay:

[image]

<sup>A330 ADIRU, [source](http://www.securiteaerienne.com/air-france-447-turbulences-ou-adiru-mise-a-jour/)</sup>

They process probes inputs and compute altitude, airspeed, vertical speed, angle of attack, wind drift, air temperature, etc.

ADIRU information can be displayed on various screens. On large aircraft the content of the screens is managed to cope with failures, information can be rerouted to working displays. In normal mode, data from the left set of probes is displayed on the left seat screens, and data from the right set on the right seat screens.

[image]

<sup>Source: A330 FCOM</sup>

Altitude is usually displayed on PFD (primary displays). Here seen from the right seat:

[image]

<sup>A330 F/O screen, source: Flickr, photo by [swiss_a320](https://www.flickr.com/photos/26436024@N06/5277139719)</sup>

**Standby instruments**

Analog standby instruments are still fed with air pipes from pitot and static standby probes, in particular the standby altimeter is a barometric instrument, using an [aneroid capsule](https://www.falgayras.com/en/products/aneroid-pressure-capsules-and-bellows/).

**Radioaltimeters**

A word about radioaltimeters (RA), as they were mentioned in a comment. [Radioaltimeters](https://skybrary.aero/articles/radio-altimeter) are not altimeters, this is a misnomer, they measure height above ground level (AGL). In aviation, the word *altitude* is used exclusively for a measure of height [relative to mean sea level](https://skybrary.aero/articles/altitude-flight-level-and-height).

That said, there is not much to say, RA are exactly the same than GA or business jets aircraft. They are used for landing, to evaluate the height above the threshold, in particular the decision height which is the point where the approach must be aborted if all conditions for a landing are not met. As their name implies, this is a radar measure (roundtrip time of a wobble radio signal).

RA are one of the data sources for "one thousand", "twenty", "minimums", etc, callouts (as @Bianfable mentions barometric altitudes can also be used). On large aircraft RA are coupled with the autopilot mode to monitor the approach and trigger various alarms.

---

Comment: Why no radar altimeters?

Comment: "angle of attack probes, which are redundant": Wouldn't one wish they had been. https://www.seattletimes.com/business/boeing-aerospace/a-lack-of-redundancies-on-737-max-system-has-baffled-even-those-who-worked-on-the-jet/

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, all versions of 737 have two angle-of-attack vanes; the problem was that the specific system was not reading both of them.

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg! "*Why no radar altimeters?*": I understand the OP question as: What is the difference in altimeter technology between GA and large aircraft (*What's the mechanism of the altimeters in big jets?*"), but I have added a paragraph. Thanks.

Comment: @JanHudec Oh my. What a screw-up. Still, they weren't redundant...

Comment: @Peter, they sort of are not redundant for the other purposes either. One is connected to the captain's stick shaker and the other to the first officer's stick shaker. But if one fails, the pilots have to cross-reference the other instruments and decide for themselves whether the one stick shaker activating is spurious or not.

Comment: Great answer, but you may want to clarify that the use of the term "altitude" in aviation is used "...exclusively for a measure of height relative to mean sea level." There is **absolute altitude,** **pressure altitude,** and **density altitude.** These *altitudes* are not a measure of height relative to mean sea level. Thanks

Comment: @757toga: In these sentences, "altitude" is indeed a reference to MSL, e.g. *pressure altitude* is a wording defined in [WMO vocabulary](https://library.wmo.int/?lvl=notice_display&id=220): "*Standard pressure altitude - Altitude corresponding in the standard atmosphere to a specific pressure.*"

Comment: I would remove the image for a piezoelectric sensor, since that type of sensor cannot typically measure steady state pressure.

Comment: @Sanchises: Thanks for pointing out. I replace the image by what I believe is the actual module used on A330 (Honeywell). Do you know the actual transducer technology used?

Comment: @Bianfable: Thanks. note in this section I just emphasize RA are not used for navigation like barometric altimeters. The similarity between RA and barometric minimums is another whole topic. However I improved the last sentence to not exclude pressure-altitude from callout sources.

Comment: They say "solid state silicon" so my guess would be a piezoresistive sensor measuring the strain in a membrane.

Comment: @Sanchises: Yes, "*The IPT, HPA/B, PPT, PPT2 and PPTR/E family use a micromachined silicon die with piezoresistive strain gauges.*". [Source](https://aerospace.honeywell.com/content/dam/aerobt/en/documents/learn/products/sensors/user-documentation/N61-1410-000-000-Precision-Pressure-Transducers-And-Barometers-FAQs.pdf).